# Pandas dataframe groupby datetime month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

Consider a CSV file:

```
string,date,number
a string,2/5/11 9:16am,1.0
a string,3/5/11 10:44pm,2.0
a string,4/22/11 12:07pm,3.0
a string,4/22/11 12:10pm,4.0
a string,4/29/11 11:59am,1.0
a string,5/2/11 1:41pm,2.0
a string,5/2/11 2:02pm,3.0
a string,5/2/11 2:56pm,4.0
a string,5/2/11 3:00pm,5.0
a string,5/2/14 3:02pm,6.0
a string,5/2/14 3:18pm,7.0
```

I can read this in, and reformat the date column into datetime format:

```
b = pd.read_csv('b.dat')
b['date'] = pd.to_datetime(b['date'],format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
```

I have been trying to group the data by month. It seems like there should be an obvious way of accessing the month and grouping by that. But I can't seem to do it. Does anyone know how?

What I am currently trying is re-indexing by the date:

```
b.index = b['date']
```

I can access the month like so:

```
b.index.month
```

However I can't seem to find a function to lump together by month.

Comment: If you are struggling with applying any of the answer, please keep in mind that in this question (and therefore in the answers) the Datetime value is assigned to the index of the Dataframe. A quick tip/reminder could be the following: if you have a Datetime column, you can actually access the single Yeay/Month/Day/Hour/Minute value just by doing `my_df.my_column.dt.month`

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Managed to do it:

```
b = pd.read_csv('b.dat')
b.index = pd.to_datetime(b['date'],format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
b.groupby(by=[b.index.month, b.index.year])
```

Or

```
b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))  # update for v0.21+
```

Comment: I think the more pandonic ways are to either use `resample` (when it provides the functionality you need) or use a `TimeGrouper`: `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))`

Comment: to get the result DataFrame sum or average, `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()` or `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()`

Comment: `pd.TimeGrouper` has been deprecated in favor of `pd.Grouper`, which is a bit more flexible but still takes `freq` and `level` arguments.

Comment: the first method doesn't not appear to work. It gives the error, 'Series object has no attribute 'month'' for a Series created via `to_datetime`.

Comment: @ely The answer implicitly relies on the lines in the original question where `b` is given an index after being read from CSV. Add `b.index = pd.to_datetime(b['date'],format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')` after the line `b = pd.read_csv('b.dat')`. [I've edited the answer just now too.]

Comment: To group the months in chronological order, you need to swap the month and year index. The resulting command for the grouping being `b.groupby(by=[b.index.year, b.index.month])`.

Answer (score 119):

**(update: 2018)**

Note that `pd.Timegrouper` is depreciated and will be removed. Use instead:

```
 df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

Comment: Find the Grouper docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html?highlight=grouper) and the frequency specifications (`freq=...`) [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). Some examples are `freq=D` for **days**, `freq=B` for **business days**, `freq=W` for **weeks** or even `freq=Q` for **quarters**.

Comment: I found it useful to use 'key' to avoid having to reindex the df, as follows: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='your_date_column', freq='M'))

Comment: Does this work if you're grouping by two columns, only one of which is datetime value column?

Comment: speeding up the further research for those who want to group by specific column (or more):
df.groupby(['col1', pd.Grouper(key='date_col', freq='1M')]).agg({
        'col2': 'sum',
        'col3': 'max'
    })

Answer (score 30):

To groupby time-series data you can use the method [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). For example, to groupby by month:

```
df.resample(rule='M', on='date')['Values'].sum()
```

The list with offset aliases you can find [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer: `groupby` by time is called `resample`.

Answer (score 18):

One solution which avoids MultiIndex is to create a new `datetime` column setting day = 1. Then group by this column.

#### Normalise day of month

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2017-10-05', '2017-10-20', '2017-10-01', '2017-09-01']),
                   'Values': [5, 10, 15, 20]})

# normalize day to beginning of month, 4 alternative methods below
df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(-1) + pd.offsets.Day(1)
df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'].dt.day-1, unit='D')
df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'].map(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=1))
df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'].dt.normalize().map(pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback)
```

Then use `groupby` as normal:

```
g = df.groupby('YearMonth')

res = g['Values'].sum()

# YearMonth
# 2017-09-01    20
# 2017-10-01    30
# Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

#### Comparison with `pd.Grouper`

The subtle benefit of this solution is, unlike `pd.Grouper`, the grouper index is normalized to the *beginning* of each month rather than the end, and therefore you can easily extract groups via `get_group`:

```
some_group = g.get_group('2017-10-01')
```

Calculating the last day of October is slightly more cumbersome. [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html), as of v0.23, does support a `convention` parameter, but this is only applicable for a `PeriodIndex` grouper.

#### Comparison with string conversion

An alternative to the above idea is to convert to a string, e.g. convert datetime `2017-10-XX` to string `'2017-10'`. However, this is not recommended since you lose all the efficiency benefits of a `datetime` series (stored internally as numerical data in a contiguous memory block) versus an `object` series of strings (stored as an array of pointers).

Comment: See this answer for the proper way to utilize offsets when there are already day=1 values : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831333/9987623.

Comment: @AlexK, does `pd.tseries.offsets` have an advantage over `pd.tseries.MonthBegin` ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know enough to tell those apart. I just added the comment because your `df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)` code above changes any date that is already the first of the month to the first of the previous month.

Comment: @AlexK, Good spot, have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: For beginning of month with `Grouper`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56280791/10495893

Answer (score 11):

Slightly alternative solution to @jpp's but outputting a `YearMonth` string:

```
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda x: '{year}-{month}'.format(year=x.year, month=x.month))

res = df.groupby('YearMonth')['Values'].sum()
```

Comment: Helpful in the case where you don't want to set your date column as an index

Comment: Can also generate strings using dt.strfrtime: `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y %b.')`