# Pandas datetime anchored offset for (-) MonthBegin doesn't work as expected

Tags: pandas

I need to move back to the beginning of the month but if i'm already at the beginning I want to stay there. Pandas anchored offset with n=0 is supposed to do exactly that but it doesn't produce the expected results between the anchored points for the (-) MonthBegin .

For example for this
`pd.Timestamp('2017-01-06 00:00:00') - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=0)` 
I expect to move me back to `Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')`
but instead I get `Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00')`
What am I doing wrong? Or you think it's a bug?

I can also see that the same rule works fine for the MonthEnd so combining the 2 like below `pd.Timestamp('2017-01-06 00:00:00')+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)-pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)`
I get the desired effect of `Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')` but my expectation for it to work with just `- pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=0)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed the correct behavior that is witnessed which are part of the rules laid out in *Anchored Offset Semantics* for offsets supporting *start/end*  of a particular frequency offset.

Consider the given example:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin

pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00') - MonthBegin(n=0)
Out[18]:
Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00')
```

Note that the anchor point corresponding to `MonthBegin` offset is set as first of every month. Now, since the given timestamp clearly surpasses this day, these would automatically be treated as though it were a part of the next month and rolling (whether forward or backwards) would come into play only after that.

> <sub>excerpt from [**docs**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics)</sub>  
>   For the case when n=0, the date is not moved if on an anchor point,
>   otherwise it is rolled forward to the next anchor point.

---

To get what you're after, you need to provide `n=1` which would roll the timestamp to the correct date.

```
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00') - MonthBegin(n=1)
Out[20]:
Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
```

If you had set the date on the exact anchor point, then also it would give you the desired result as per the attached docs.

```
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00') - MonthBegin(n=0)
Out[21]:
Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: chris-b1 at github had this comment: 
offsets only have a notion of an n, not special behavior for addition or subtraction. In other words:

   (date + offset(n=-5)) == (date - offset(n=5))
   (date + offset(n=0) == (date - offset(n=0)
n=0 has always been somewhat odd - from the DateOffset docstring.

"""
...
    Zero presents a problem.  Should it roll forward or back?  We
    arbitrarily have it rollforward:

    date + BDay(0) == BDay.rollforward(date)

    Since 0 is a bit weird, we suggest avoiding its use.
"""

Comment: to recap for future use if you want to move to the beginning of the month & stay within that month no matter what your starting point is use  
`pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00')+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)-pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)`  
`pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)-pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)`  
both yield  
`Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')`  
no such issue exists with moving to month end (and sticking within the month )
so just use `+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)`

Answer (score 10):

To jump to the month's start, use:

```
ts + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0) - pd.tseries.offse‌​ts.MonthBegin(n=1)
```

Yes, it's ugly, but it's the only method to jump to the first of the month while *staying* there if `ts` is already the first.

Quick demo:

```
>>> pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,12,30), dt.datetime(2017,2,2)).to_series() \
        + MonthEnd(n=0) - MonthBegin(n=1)

2016-12-30   2016-12-01
2016-12-31   2016-12-01
2017-01-01   2017-01-01
2017-01-02   2017-01-01
...
2017-01-31   2017-01-01
2017-02-01   2017-02-01
2017-02-02   2017-02-01
```

Comment: Or, in the same spirit and almost equally ugly, but with only one offset : `+ MonthBegin(1) - MonthBegin(1)`