# pandas split dates into months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has the begin date and end date of each event (like the table below)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFHPe.png)

Is there a datetime tool in pandas that can help me convert this into a dataframe like the table below

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crod0.png)

If there is no pandas function, what is the best way to accomplish this result?
Thanks!

Comment: Please try to be more specific, it is unclear what you want to achieve and what you already tried.

Comment: Looks like you would want to group by the months with time series data, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083253/3006366

Comment: So the original dataframe contains: `id`, `start_date` and `end_date` and you want to create a new dataframe with: `id`, month and year taken from `start_date` and minutes that is the difference between  `start_date` and `end_date`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. I want the minutes allocated to each month between the start date and end date