# Pandas grouping by start of the month with pd.Grouper

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with hourly timestamps:

```
2019-01-01 0:00:00             1
2019-01-01 1:00:00             2
2019-01-11 3:00:00             1
2019-01-21 4:00:00             2
2019-02-01 0:00:00             1
2019-03-05 1:00:00             2
2019-03-21 3:00:00             1
2019-04-08 4:00:00             2
```

I am using the Pandas Grouper to group and sum the data monthly:

```
monthly_data = [pd.Grouper(freq='M', label='left')].sum()
```

Expected output:

```
2019-01-01 0:00:00             6
2019-02-01 0:00:00             1
2019-03-01 0:00:00             3
2019-04-01 0:00:00             2
```

Actual output:

```
2018-12-31 0:00:00             6
2019-01-31 0:00:00             1
2019-02-28 0:00:00             3
2019-03-30 0:00:00             2
```

How can I get the labels of the groups to be the first element in the group?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the freq MS (Month Start), rather than M (Month End).

*See [dateoffset objects in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).*

Comment: Is there a way to make this systematic ? i.e. to make sure that whatever freq chosen, the label corresponds to the start of the periods ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `resample` to aggregate on `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.resample('MS').sum()

            value
date             
2019-01-01      6
2019-02-01      1
2019-03-01      3
2019-04-01      2
```