# How to groupby specifically datetime index in a multiindex column by month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

- The data frame shows the date with the amount of import and export
  and it is further bifurcated into coastal and regional data per day
  of one month.
- What I **wish** to achieve is to club i.e sum all the data presented, which is of one month in this 
  case, in the end, it will show only one entry that will be of month
  ending date and **adding** all the corresponding fields.

This is the following code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('output.csv',
             encoding="utf-8",skipinitialspace=True,engine='python')
datadf = df

datadf = datadf.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')  

datadf = datadf.astype({'ForeignType' : 'category','ImportType' : 'category','ArrDate' : 'datetime64',
                        'DepDate' : 'datetime64'})

# datadf = datadf.groupby(datadf['ArrDate'].dt.strftime('%B'))['ComoQty'].sum()
datadf1 = datadf.groupby(['ArrDate','ImportType','ForeignType'])['ComoQty'].sum()
datadf2 = datadf1.to_frame()
datadf2.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
# datadf2 = datadf2.reset_index('ImportType')
# datadf2 = datadf2.reset_index('ForeignType')
# datadf2 = datadf2.reset_index('ArrDate')
datadf2
```

[image: Output by running the above code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas dataframe groupby datetime month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082784/pandas-dataframe-groupby-datetime-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datadf1 = datadf.drop(columns='Unnamed: 0')
prac = datadf1
prac =prac.set_index('ArrDate')
prac_dates = prac.copy()

prac = prac.resample('D').apply({'ShipName':'count','ComoQty':'sum'}).reset_index()

prac_dates = ((prac_dates.resample('M').apply({'ComoQty':'sum'}))/1000).reset_index()
prac_dates['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(prac_dates['ArrDate']).strftime('%B')
del prac_dates['ArrDate']
# prac_dates

prac['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(prac['ArrDate']).strftime('%B')
# prac['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(prac['Month'], format='%B')
prac['ArrDate'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(prac['ArrDate']).strftime('%d')
```