# How can I compute average monthly value from large daily JSON dataset in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm relatively new to working with pandas dataframes to read in data and I'm having some trouble working with my dataset. I've been reading many other StackOverflow posts on a similar problem but I've been having trouble applying those solutions to my case possibly because of the structure of my JSON data. My JSON data as arranged into my dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)` generally looks like this

```html
             dateTime                          value
0   01/16/20 04:32:42   {'bpm': 70, 'confidence': 0}
1   01/16/20 04:32:57   {'bpm': 70, 'confidence': 0}
2   01/16/20 04:33:12   {'bpm': 70, 'confidence': 1}
```

and so on for many daily values.

My goal is to read all of this raw daily data and compute a monthly average of "bpm" and plot to a matplot graph. My problem is I'm having trouble using pandas datetime or mean() operations because I don't think pandas accepts my dateTime format as actually in datetime and when I try to use mean() it gives me an `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` error.

How can I use built in pandas tools to allow me to compute a monthly average by grouping my daily values together based on the month?

```html
for file in os.listdir(data_dir):  # look at every file in the folder
    if file.startswith("heart_rate") and file.endswith(".json"):  # only want heart_rate-date.json files
        with open(os.path.join(data_dir, file)) as f:  # open each file in data_dir
            data = json.load(f)
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
            print(df)
            #df.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.dateTime)
            #df['Month'] = df['dateTime'].dt.month
            for i, j in enumerate(data):
                if data[i]['value']['confidence'] > 0:
                    daily_avg_bpm += data[i]['value']['bpm']
                    daily_date = data[i]['dateTime'].split()[0]
                    my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(daily_date, "%m/%d/%y").date()
                    days.append(my_date)
            months.append(daily_date[:2])
            daily_avg_bpm /= len(data)
            dates.append(daily_date)
            avg_bpms.append(round(daily_avg_bpm))
        f.close()
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Heart Rate')
plt.title("Fitbit Heart Rate")
for i, j in enumerate(dates):
    plt.plot(dates[i], avg_bpms[i])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did `resample` solve your issue?

Comment: Hi Prayson,

Unfortunately not yet. I was trying to apply your suggestion but I was having errors with the apply() and I've been getting list indices must. Now I'm getting DataError     raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.

Comment: It means you do not have numerical values to resample. What do you get by `df.dtypes`?

Comment: My dataframe values look like the example shown in my question with datetime and value. The numerical values I want are the ['values']['bpm'] values but df.dtypes gives me an error TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: As you see, you have Series not DataFrame. So the example data are not the same. Can you try `df['value'].apply(pd.Series)` ? Does that expand value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way it to transform your `values` to columns and cast `dateTime` to actual datetime. With that you can use `resample` to aggregate on the frequency desire:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'dateTime':[ '01/16/20 04:32:42', '01/16/20 04:32:57', '02/16/20 04:33:12', '03/16/20 04:33:12'],
'value': [{'bpm': 70, 'confidence': 0}, {'bpm': 75, 'confidence': 0},  
          {'bpm': 73, 'confidence': 1}, {'bpm': 78, 'confidence': 1}]})

# expland 
df = data['value'].apply(pd.Series)

# to datetime and set index 
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dateTime'])
df.set_index('dateTime', inplace=True)

# data resample to Monthy with mean 
example = df.resample('M', kind='period').mean()

# plot
example['bpm'].plot(title="Fitbit Heart Rate", xlabel="Month", ylabel="Heart Rate");
```

#### Note:

For a graph to show, make sure you have data with N > 1 of the selected frequency. So if the frequency is "M" for Month, make sure there are at least 2 months in the dataset.

Read [Pandas `resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: `UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left == right == 600.0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
  ax.set_xlim(left, right)
` and shows nothing.

Comment: That is because we only have data for one month. So you will not see anything. change the date above to `['01/16/20 04:32:42', '01/16/20 04:32:57', '02/16/20 04:33:12']` and you will see the chart. Note: I have update data to reflect it

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your data, so this might not work right away. But except that you should be able to use this method.

Steps

1. Convert `value` column's dict values into columns ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231651/454773))
2. Group By ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082784/pandas-dataframe-groupby-datetime-month))
3. Average ([Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html))

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
# Step 1
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['value'], axis=1), df['value'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
# Step 2
df.groupby(by=[df.dateTime])
# Step 3
print(df['bpm'].mean().sort_values())
```

Comment: I'm confused about the line `print(df['bpm'].mean().sort_values())` because df['bpm'].mean() returns a float value so this code throws the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'sort_values'` Do you mean collect these values in a column and then sort?