# Find sum of each month Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv("wind_data.csv")
df = df[['SETTLEMENTDATE', 'wind']].copy()

dataset = df.set_index("SETTLEMENTDATE")
dataset.index = pd.to_datetime(dataset.index)
print(dataset.head())
print(dataset.shape)
```

Dataset

[image]

In this dataset I want to calculate wind data for each month. (I need only 12 rows of this data set instead 105350)

Can you please help me?

Comment: For the wind stats, do you want average, max, min? or something more complex?   I think you can use groupby and pd.grouper as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082784/pandas-dataframe-groupby-datetime-month or the resample method highlighted by ansev already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
dataset.resample('M')['wind'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using a groupby:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("wind_data.csv")
df = df[['SETTLEMENTDATE', 'wind']].copy()

dataset['SETTLEMENTMONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['SETTLEMENTDATE']).dt.floor('M')

dataset.groupby('SETTLEMENTMONTH')['wind'].sum()
```