# Pandas + GroupBy DateTime with time threshold across days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Is there a way to use groupby with a time threshold?  Lets assume a 5min time threshold. For example, groupby times that are within 1min of eachother.  The datetimes will be monitonically increase, but may span across multiple days.

|  | Cents | ED_YF | Vals | EventTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-27 13:41:01 |
| 11 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-27 13:41:01 |
| 12 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 |
| 13 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 |
| 14 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 |
| 15 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 |
| 4 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-29 16:41:00 |
| 5 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-29 16:41:00 |

I've seen it used in a merge_asof, where a threshold is a provided input, but I havent seen anything similar in the Panda docs for a GroupBy... In this example, I'm looking to add a column ["GroupID"] (.ngroup()) based on the column EventTimestamp:

|  | Cents | ED_YF | Vals | EventTimestamp | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-27 13:41:01 | 0 |
| 11 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-27 13:41:01 | 0 |
| 12 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 | 1 |
| 13 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 | 1 |
| 14 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2 |
| 15 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2 |
| 4 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-29 16:41:00 | 3 |
| 5 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-29 16:41:00 | 3 |

Thanks!

EDIT: I have tried using df['GroupID'] = (df['EventTimestamp'].diff() >= pd.Timedelta('1T')).cumsum(), but this doesn't work across multiple days.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082784/pandas-dataframe-groupby-datetime-month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IUC, i think what you are searching for is the pd.Grouper instruction through it you can define, the freq beetween the datetimes you want to groupby

```
df['GroupId'] = df[['EventTimeStamp']].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1min')).cumcount()
```

I didnt test it out but i am pretty sure this what you looking for